# Not able to start new server instance in MySQL workbench6.0.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I just installed MYSQL workbench 6.0.7 but i m not able to get the server up. It shows the

> **Error** - The database server instance is unknown

And start server button is disabled.

Please Help

Comment: On which platform is that happening? Can you share a screenshot showing where the error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this was the second time i was trying to install MySQL(first time it had crashed).
while uninstalling the first time, it didnt remove some of the data folders.

I had to delete MySQL Data folder from C:\Documents and Settings\All Users (manually)

and reinstalled MYSQL workbench and the instance.

It is working absolutely fine now...